# Sending automated reply to Messenger API fails with token error

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm making a messenger bot which is currently in development mode. When I write a message to my Facebook page from my account (which is in Administrator role), I can't get a reply from my app.

I'm sending the following JSON encoded data to Messenger:

```
$data = ["recipient"=>["id"=>$recipientId], "messaging_type"=> "RESPONSE", "message"=>["text"=>$message]];
$json = \json_encode($data);
```

To this endpoint:

```
$prefix =  'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=';
$url = $prefix.env("FACEBOOK_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN");
```

And get back the following message from Facebook:

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"..."}}
```

This is completely the same way as in the Messenger API documentation, that's about sending messages.

I'm not trying to query any information, just send a message back to the user.

Is the endpoint incorrect in the docs? Did developers.facebook.com generate invalid page access token? Do I need some additional setting? Help me clear this up this confusion, please.

Comment: First question is: Is your access token active ?.  Second, Can you log the request headers and body, and post, using placeholders of course for any personal data

Comment: It's a never-expiring page token with the following scopes: `pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_messaging_subscriptions, public_profile`. Just a moment

Comment: Try generating page access token from developer console - Messenger -> Settings and check if it works.

Comment: We've recently faced some troubles on Facebook site at [amio.io](https://amio.io). What helped to us is to re-authenticate affected accounts (we use OAuth). So as @ssakash suggests, generating new access token would probably help!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has recently invalidated access tokens of more than 50m users. You've been probably affected. https://techcrunch.com/2018/09/28/facebook-says-50-million-accounts-affected-by-account-takeover-bug/

Comment: Facebook apps use page-specific user access tokens and page access tokens, which were not affected.

Comment: We were affected in our case as we use OAuth to Facebook in Amio.